# It'll make it quicker

Tags: expletive-pronoun

Is "It'll make it quicker" natural in the following dialogue?

Peter: Why not take the taxi to the airport?

John: Great idea! It'll make it quicker (by taxi).

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Why not? Surely you can say so. Can't say if it's idiomatic or not but it's not wrong. You can say, "**I'll get there quicker this way**"

Comment: It's grammatical but not idiomatic.  "**We'll** *make it* (there) quicker by taxi".   To make it = to arrive at a place or destination.   But if you're using **make it** to mean "cause it to be", then *It'll make it quicker.* where "It will" = "Going by taxi will" and the second "it" is the trip; in that case, "by taxi" couldn't be tacked onto the end of the sentence: {Going by taxi} will make it quicker {by taxi}.

Comment: If you want "make it" to mean "cause it to be", then, instead of "by taxi", you could say "It'll make it quicker *if we go by taxi*" or "... quicker *going by taxi*"

Comment: In "It'll make it quicker going by taxi," the first "it" refers to "going by taxi," doesn't it? However, it seems to me that the expletive can also refer to a prepositional phrase denoting a situation, as in "It looked very Christmassy with lights on the trees."

Comment: @Apollyon: You have to decide what meaning of "make it" is operative here. If you mean it as "arrive", then the subject must be "We", not "going by taxi". Going by taxi does not arrive.  We arrive, going by taxi.  *We will make it there quicker by taxi*.  If you mean "make it" as "cause it to be", then "going by taxi" can be the subject, but then *by taxi* is not a valid complement to"quicker":  It [going by taxi] will make it [the trip] quicker **by taxi**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Alternatively it'll make the journey quicker.

Comment: Are you a native speaker of English?

Comment: @Apollyon no it is not my mother tongue so i'm not a native speaker.